# Binary JPEG files are corrupted using socket recv()

Tags: c++, sockets, binaryfiles, recv

I'm trying to PUT a binary JPEG file from client to server using sockets in C++. The JPEG file gets transferred fine most times. However, there are times where it gets transferred with a larger file size and the photo has pixelated sections. What could be the issue?

Here is my code on the server side that uses recv():

```
void FtpThread::CPut(std::vector<std::string>& Arguments)
{
    //filesize of file being put on server
    const int size = atoi(Arguments[2].c_str());

    char *memblock;
    memblock = new char[size];      
    //Sets memblock to 0's
    memset(memblock, 0, size);

    //send client a confirmation - 150 ok to send data
    send(s, Ftp::R150_PUT.c_str(), Ftp::R150_PUT.length(), 0);

    //stores the return value of recv()
    int r;

    char currentPath[FILENAME_MAX];
    std::string filePath;
    //gets the full path of the current working directory 
    _getcwd(currentPath, sizeof(currentPath) / sizeof(TCHAR));
    filePath = currentPath + std::string("\\") + FtpThread::FILE_DIRECTORY + std::string("\\") + Arguments[1];


    //open file (output file stream)
    std::ofstream file(filePath, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary|std::ios::trunc);

    if (file.is_open())
    {   
        //while memory blocks are still being received
        while ((r = recv(ds, memblock, FtpThread::BUFFERSIZE, 0)) != 0) 
        {
            //if there's a socket error, abort
            if (r == SOCKET_ERROR) 
            {
                std::cerr << "WSA Error Code:" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                //send client "Requested action aborted. Local error in processing."
                send(s, Ftp::R451.c_str(), Ftp::R451.length(), 0);
                file.close();
                closesocket(ds);
                return;
            }

            //write client's file blocks to file on server
            file.write(memblock, FtpThread::BUFFERSIZE);
        }

        closesocket(ds);

        delete[] memblock;

        //finished sending memory blocks; file is completely transferred.
        file.close();

        //let client know "226 File send OK"
        send(s, Ftp::R226_PUT.c_str(), Ftp::R226_PUT.length(), 0);
    } 
    else //if no such file exists on server - send a "550 Failed to open file"
    {
        send(s, Ftp::R550.c_str(), Ftp::R550.length(), 0);
    }
}
```

Here is my code on the client side that uses send():

```
std::ifstream::pos_type size;
        char* memblock;

        std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);

        if (file.is_open())
        {
            size = file.tellg();

            if(size > 0)
            {
                memblock = new char[size];
                file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
                file.read(memblock, size);
                file.close();
                sendData(memblock, size);

                delete[] memblock;
            }

            closesocket(sockData);

            handleResponse();
        }
```

Comment: maybe the allocated memblock is too small, meaning < than BUFFERSIZE

Comment: BUFFERSIZE is set currently at 4096. The size of memblock is set to the size of the photo being transferred. The photo that is getting corrupted is 187786 in size.

Comment: I am talking of the size of the memblock in the receiver code, you don't know the image size there...

Comment: Do you use binary transfer mode for file? Maybe text one is set by default.

Comment: How would I check the transfer mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file.write(memblock, FtpThread::BUFFERSIZE);
```

should be

```
file.write(memblock, r);
```

You're assuming that recv() fills the buffer.

Comment: You must have a better feed than I do - you always seem to get these freebies before me:)